# Should a TypeConverter that is meant to convert to and from MyClass be able to convert MyClass

Tags: c#, typeconverter

Suppose I have a MyClass that has a TypeConverter

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    // Insert code here.
}

public class MyClassConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(Type destType)
    {
        // Insert code here.
    }
}
... etc
```

Should MyClassConverter be able to convert objects of Type MyClass?

And if so, If MyClassConverter is asked to convert an object of MyClass to an object of MyClass, should it return the original MyClass or a copy of it?

I see that Micosoft has some inconsistent behaviour:

```cs
int i = 4;
TypeConverter typeConverter = new TypeConverter();
bool b = typeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(int))
```

b appears to equal false. I see similar behaviour if I want to convert an System.Drawing.Point to a System.Drawing.Point using PointConverter. But apparently a string CanConvertTo a string, but a System.Drawing.Color can't be converted to System.Drawing.Color by the ColorConverter. So it has nothing to do with value types or reference types.

Other question: if MyTypeConverter CanConvertFrom(typeof(X)) and MyTypeConverter CanConvertTo(typeof(Y), should MyTypeConverter be able to convert from type X to type Y?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty important to understand why type converters exist.  They are *glue* that make the various designers in Visual Studio work.  With their principal role to convert back and forth between an object of a specific type and a *string*.  A string that you look at in the designer and you can edit to change the object.

The Framework has lots of built-in TypeConverters.  Like PointConverter and ColorConverter.  Their CanConvertFrom() methods only say "go ahead" if the sourceType argument is `System.String`.  And a matching ConvertFrom() method that only has the code to parse the string.  Which is all they ever *have* to do when a Point or Color is displayed in a PropertyGrid or the built-in Property Window.

You can certainly make a custom TypeConverter do anything you want.  It just isn't that clear that you'll run into a practical use-case, unless you write the code to use the TypeConverter explicitly.

The diagnostic for a *false* return in your code snippet is that you simply didn't implement CanConvertFrom() correctly.  Hard to tell, you omitted the code.  It will have to recognize typeof(int) explicitly.  And of course have the required code to convert from an *int* to a *bool* in the ConvertFrom() method.

Comment: The examples in my code were return values from Microsoft's type converters, not mine. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I was wondering what would be neater: give my class a cast operator / converter method, or create a separate type converter class. Your answer made clear that these type converter are mainly meant to be used in bindingsource and such